# Props Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

guys am in need of assistance,  i am passing a prop from my products.jsx file to my product.jsx file, and am getting the error

```
Product.jsx:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

heres my Products.jsx file

```
import React from 'react';
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import Product from './Product/Product';

const products =[
    {id: 1 , name: 'Shoes', description: 'walking shoes', price: '#5'},
    {id: 2 , name: 'apple', description: 'macbook', price: '#10'},
];



const Products = () => {

        return ( 
    <Main>
        <Grid container justify="center" spacing={4}>
            {products.map((product) => (
                <Grid item key={product.id} xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
                    <Product product={product}/>
                </Grid>
            ))}
        </Grid>
    </Main>

        )
}

export default Products
```

and heres my product.jsx file

```
import React from 'react'
import { Card, CardMedia, CardContent, CardActions, Typography, IconButton } from '@material-ui/core';
import { AddShoppingCart } from '@material-ui/icons';
import useStyles from './styles'

const Product = ({ product }) => {

    const classes = useStyles();
    
    return (
        <Card className={classes.root}>
            <CardMedia className={classes.media} image='' title={product.name} />
              <CardContent>
                        <div className={classes.cardContent}>
                            <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                                {product.name}
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                                {product.price}
                            </Typography>
                        </div>
                        <Typography variant="h2" color="textSecondary" component="p">{product.description}</Typography>
              </CardContent>
              <CardActions disableSpacing className={classes.cardActions}>
                    <IconButton aria-label="Add to Cart">
                    <AddShoppingCart />
                    </IconButton>
              </CardActions>
        </Card>
    )
}

export default Product
```

i dont seem to see the error , it is not supposed to give me cannot read property name error please help

Comment: can you share your json response as well to identify your issue

Comment: thats the json response, Product.jsx:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks perfect and it should work without any issue, but just to be safe, use null propagation to avoid accessing undefined prop.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Card, CardMedia, CardContent, CardActions, Typography, IconButton } from '@material-ui/core';
import { AddShoppingCart } from '@material-ui/icons';
import useStyles from './styles'

const Product = ({ product }) => {

    const classes = useStyles();
    
    return (
        <Card className={classes.root}>
            <CardMedia className={classes.media} image='' title={product?.name} />
              <CardContent>
                        <div className={classes.cardContent}>
                            <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                                {product?.name}
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                                {product?.price}
                            </Typography>
                        </div>
                        <Typography variant="h2" color="textSecondary" component="p">{product?.description}</Typography>
              </CardContent>
              <CardActions disableSpacing className={classes.cardActions}>
                    <IconButton aria-label="Add to Cart">
                    <AddShoppingCart />
                    </IconButton>
              </CardActions>
        </Card>
    )
}

export default Product
```

Comment: thanks your suggestion worked, i have this error now ```Failed prop type: Material-UI: Either `children`, `image`, `src` or `component` prop must be specified.```

Comment: it's related to ```CardMedia``` component of Material-UI. This question has been already discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55290345/material-ui-either-image-or-src-property-must-be-specified

Answer (score 1):

Use null check to avoid such an issue.

Products.jsx

```
    const Products = () => {
       return ( 
        <Main>
            <Grid container justify="center" spacing={4}>
                {products && products.map((product) => (
                    <Grid item key={product.id} xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
                        <Product product={product}/>
                    </Grid>
                ))}
            </Grid>
        </Main>
   )}
```

Product.jsx

```
const Product = ({ product }) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <Card className={classes.root}>
            <CardMedia className={classes.media} image='' title={product?.name} />
              <CardContent>
                        <div className={classes.cardContent}>
                            <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                                {product?.name}
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                                {product?.price}
                            </Typography>
                        </div>
                        <Typography variant="h2" color="textSecondary" component="p">{product.description}</Typography>
              </CardContent>
              <CardActions disableSpacing className={classes.cardActions}>
                    <IconButton aria-label="Add to Cart">
                    <AddShoppingCart />
                    </IconButton>
              </CardActions>
        </Card>
    )
}
```

Comment: wow, the error seems to have gone but now i get ```Failed prop type: Material-UI: Either `children`, `image`, `src` or `component` prop must be specified.```

Comment: @opiaaustin assign an image URL to image='" (<CardMedia className={classes.media} image='' title={product?.name} />)

Comment: do you mean ```image="(<CardMedia className={classes.media} image='' title={product?.name} />)"```. just like that?

Comment: @opiaaustin like this <CardMedia className={classes.media} image={'https://i.picsum.photos/id/1035/5854/3903.jpg?hmac=DV0AS2MyjW6ddofvSIU9TVjj1kewfh7J3WEOvflY8TM'} title={product?.name} />

Comment: @opiaaustin if the answer is helpful for you please mark it accepted...Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

For me it was solved by removing a useless parenthesis

```
(
 {
    current-code
 }
)
```

***remove the parenthesis